# set_index does not effectively set the index

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have imported a timeseries dataset in pandas from a csv file.

```
data = pd.read_csv('djia_data.csv')
data.set_index('date')
```

When I print the header with`data.head()`, I correctly get

[image]

If instead I visualize the dataframe (double click on the variable in VS code with Jupiter), I get this

[image]

I do not understand while I do not get date as the new index anymore.
If instead I type

```
data = pd.read_csv('djia_data.csv')
data.set_index('date',inplace=True)
data.head()
```

I get this

[image]

When I visualize again the dataframe as a variable instead I obtain

[image]

In this case, date column is empty. I've searched on the net but I wasn't able to solve it. Can you please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The operation is not in place, use `data = data.set_index('date')`

Comment: I have tried it previously but again I obtain the same as in the last picture (date column is empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set index earlier:

```
data = pd.read_csv('djia_data.csv', index_col='date', parse_dates=['date'])
```

Comment: Same as before. The date column is empty as in the last picture. Could be just a visualization problem in VS Code?

Comment: Ok but if you print your dataframe do you see the index? (I think this is a problem of visualization of VS Code)

Comment: Yes. I confirm! thank you very much.